# Find pairs of distinct digits in pattern

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a six digit set of numbers, is my method correct to find 3 pairs of distinct digits (ex:312231)

C(10,3) * C(6,3) * C(4,2) * C(2,2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\checkmark$ You are counting the ways to select 3 kinds of pairs from 10, then select places for each pair from 6 positions.

$${^{10}C_3}{^6C_2}{^4C_2}{^2C_2}={10\choose 3}{6\choose 2,2,2} = \frac{10!\,6!}{3!\,7!\,2!^3}$$

Comment: I'm coming up with 90 per your solution, is that correct?

Comment: @RustyShackleford $10800$.  I didn't realise the OP was selecting kinds of pairs first.  Edited

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I was a bit confused at first but just figured I was wrong